# HDRI does not work properly after opening saved file

Tags: sculpting, hdri

Yesterday, I saved a file that had an active HDRI. Today, I opened the file and the HDRI is no longer displayed although shows that it is active in the world properties tab. I tried implementing the process again, but the screen no longer turns pink when I set the color to Environment Texture.

I'm stumped. If anyone has knowledge on the topic I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: By default blender does not save the images as part of the file. If the image is in a different folder on your hard drive blender cannot find it and will display pink instead. Please don ask unrelated questions on the same post. Ask the second question separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the HDRI in Blender by going to the file tab in the upper left corner, and selecting **external files**. This will give you an option to pack all external files into the .blend so that you can save it in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nate. Much appreciated.